# How would you display Data from the API to the User after they have typed in their specific information?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently making a simple website using React that lets you type in your motorcycle's Make, Model, and Year. When you type those in you hit "Find Motorcycle." The current issue is trying to get the Motorcycle data from the API and Display it to the user.

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Model  from './Model'
import Button from './Button'
import Year from './Year'

function App() {



  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Make: </h2>
      <input></input>
      <Model />
      <Year /> <br></br>
      <Button />
    </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

```
import React from "react";
import  Axios  from 'axios'

function Button () { 
    
    return (
        <div> 
            <button onClick={findMotorcycle}>Find</button>
        </div>
    )
}


    const findMotorcycle = () => {
        Axios.get("'https://motorcycle-specs-database.p.rapidapi.com/article/2012/BMW/F%20800%20GS%20Trophy'").then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data.content);
        })
    }

export default Button
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using RapidAPI to build your own API, seeing the code in your API route (the code on RapidAPI) would help see what the server is doing to respond to your API request.

---

Store the users input via a useState hook:

```js
const [make, setMake] = useState()
const [model, setModel] = useState()
const [year, setYear] = useState()
```

These should change when the user interacts with the inputs calling the associated function to update the value

In your React code above you should change your Axios request to send the values (through a GET request as query parameters) to the API function which should use the variables to return a value

```js
const findMotorcycle = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`/motorcycle?make=${make}&model=${model}&year=${year}`);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```